# ggplot on ggmap with coloured point dependent on value

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

My data set denotes the location (lat, long) of bee hives and how many in that location are positive for a parasite.

plotting the locations on a map is fine but I would like to change the colours of the points that have a parasite presence e.g. heading 'Positive' > 0

I have tried the following code but I can't + to a map it tells me it can't add 0 to a plot

```
myMap + ggplot(honeybee, aes(x= Long, y= Lat)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = cut(Positive, c(-1, 0, 5))), size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual( values = c("red", "black"), 
                     name = "Parasite", labels = c("Absent", "Present"))
```

Essentially I want the above code fitted to a ggmap

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example. If your `myMap` is a `ggmap()`, you cannot  `+ ggplot`. `ggmap()` includes `ggplot()` and you can only use `ggplot()` one time. Try `myMap + geom_point(data = honeybee, aes(.....) ......`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure where you get your map, since you did not include the data, but here's how you could do it with `ggmap`. There's no need to call ggplot again. Just include your `honeybee` datasource directly in the layer

```
library(ggmap)
m <- get_map("New York City", zoom=14,maptype="toner",source="stamen")
myMap <- ggmap(m)
honeybee <- data.frame(Lat=runif(20,min=40.69, max=40.73),
                       Long=runif(20, min=-74.03, max=-73.98),
                       Positive = rnorm(20)) 


myMap + 
  geom_point(data=honeybee, 
             mapping=aes(x= Long, y= Lat, colour = Positive>0), 
             size = 5) +
  scale_color_manual( values = c("red", "yellow"), 
                      name = "Parasite", 
                      labels = c("Absent", "Present"))
```

Which produces
[image: honeybee]